# Sum hours and minutes from separate columns into one grand total

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

This is the result that a client of mine requires. My own sense is that this approach is not practical. How could we write formulas to achieve the following grand total?

[image: Sum separate hours and minutes columns into one grand total.]

The **Hours** column has 31 hours and the **Minutes** column has 180 minutes. So the result should be 34 hours and zero minutes. How, if at all, can formulate that?

Here is the "test data:"

```
Hours   Minutes
2       45
5       15
3       10
6       12
8       8
0       15
3       45
4       30
```

Comment: If you enter the durations as time values ("8:08") into just one cell per value, you could use a simple `SUM(B2:B9)`. Use an approriate format on all cells like "hh:mm".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For hours you can use

```
=SUM(B2:B9)+INT(SUM(C2:C9)/60)
```

And minutes you can use

```
=MOD(SUM(C2:C9),60)
```